# using pcolor to plot 2d array with different cell size in matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, plot, size, cell

i have a domain of interest and this domain will be converted onto finite difference grid with cells (rows,columns)

a 2-D array (cond) contains the conductivity values assigned to each cell in the desired domain

 when i use the pcolor command in matlab

```
pcolor(cond); shading flat
```

the output figure consider every cell as 1mx1m

 if the actual cell differs than 1m (2m, 5m, etc.)

 how could i plot using pcolor but each cell will be displayed as it's actual size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the axis with `pcolor` by putting `x` and `y` as first arguments:

```
x = 1:2:10;
y = 1:5:51;
pcolor (x, y, cond);
```

Best